# Undefined property: stdClass::$id inside view error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, model-view-controller, view

Controller :

```
 public function create(){
        $projets=projet::all();
        $collab=  DB::table('collab')->get();
        return view('chef_projet.addtache',compact('projets'),compact('collab'));
    }
}
```

view :

```
  <select class="ui dropdown" name="collab">
         @foreach ($collab as $value)
     <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
   </select>
```

but i got this error: Undefined property: stdClass::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\pfe gestion du projet\gestion_projet\resources\views\chef_projet\addtache.blade.php)

Comment: What are the column names for `collab`? Make sure to match the case. You can try `@json($value)` on your blade inside of your loop to see what it contains

Comment: yeah i forget i retrieve just name column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check that in the collab table you have the id field.